# How To Replace UITabBar With UIToolBar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a Tab Based App.  When I am in a UIWebView, I want the TabBar to hide and be replaced with a UIToolBar.

Right now I utilize the following:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES]; 
    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
}
```

What this results in is the TabBar hiding the space it took is just blank white, and the toolbar is displayed above this blank white space.  How can  I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set appropriate frame of the toolbar and then add in the main window in the application in viewDidAppear mathod

Comment: I already have the toolbar all ready and configured in the view in IB.

Comment: Got it `detailViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;`

Comment: @Faisal, thanks so much for mentioning your solution, really helped me out. :)